# AzCopy inside docker image?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, azure, aws-lambda, azcopy

I am trying to make a lambda function that runs inside AWS to copy a file from S3 to Azure using the "azcopy copy" command (V10). To do that, I've created a docker image with azcopy installed inside it.
I am required to use an external proxy (something like  http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80), so the other party can control access to my IP address only.

My Dockerfile is something like this:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
RUN yum -y update && \
    yum -y install \
    gzip \
    wget \
    tar \
    && yum clean all
RUN wget https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux && \
    tar -vxf downloadazcopy-v10-linux && \
    cd azcopy_linux_amd64_10.14.1 && \
    mv azcopy .. && rm NOTICE.txt && cd .. && \
    rmdir azcopy_linux_amd64_10.14.1/ && \
    rm downloadazcopy-v10-linux
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade pip \
    && python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade wheel \
    && python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --upgrade setuptools \
    && python3 -m pip install boto3 \
    && python3 -m pip install awslambdaric \
    && python3 -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt
COPY app.py ./
RUN chmod 644 $(find . -type f) && \
    chmod 755 $(find . -type d) && \
    chmod +x azcopy
RUN yum -y install net-tools
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID <mykey>
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY <mysecret>
ENV AWS_REGION sa-east-1
ENV DEBUG TRUE
ENV LINK "'https://<my_azcopy_link>"
ENV PROXY http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80
ENV HTTP_PROXY http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80
ENV HTTPS_PROXY http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

My python code just loads the file from my S3 bucket and calls azcopy like this:

```
AZCOPY_LOG_LOCATION=/tmp AZCOPY_CONCURRENCY_VALUE=2 AZCOPY_CONCURRENT_FILES=1 /var/task/azcopy copy . 'https://<mylink>' --recursive --cap-mbps 20
```

Outside my docker image, running this command directly seems to work. However, inside docker he gets stuck without ever transferring anything (my timeout is 5 min.):

```
START RequestId: 2bb96291-240b-4d35-a2bd-0400df4366e0 Version: $LATEST
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Proxy detected: https://azcopyvnextrelease.blob.core.windows.net -> http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job b44c7ab0-c0cf-0d44-7466-7a4283a7a5bc has started
Log file is located at: /tmp/b44c7ab0-c0cf-0d44-7466-7a4283a7a5bc.log

INFO: Proxy detected: https://external_addr.blob.core.windows.net -> http://proxy-something.azure.aztec.cloud.something:80
0.0 %, 0 Done, 0 Failed, 2 Pending, 0 Skipped, 2 Total, 09 May 2022 13:30:31,183 [WARNING] (rapid) Reset initiated: Timeout
END RequestId: 2bb96291-240b-4d35-a2bd-0400df4366e0
REPORT RequestId: 2bb96291-240b-4d35-a2bd-0400df4366e0  Duration: 300000.00 ms  Billed Duration: 300000 ms      Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 3008 MB
```

I can't make this code work even in my local machine. If I run this lambda in the cloud, the same thing happens.

What am I doing wrong? What could I do?

Comment: [Authenticating azcopy or az storage cli to upload to Azurite docker emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066507/authenticating-azcopy-or-az-storage-cli-to-upload-to-azurite-docker-emulator) , [Azcopy: copy file from local machine to Azure Blob not successful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/749864/azcopy-copy-file-from-local-machine-to-azure-blob.html) and [Provide official docker image](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/423)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy empty folders with azcopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298620/copy-empty-folders-with-azcopy)

Comment: Nope. None of that worked.